# summing dataframe values based on unique grouping of column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i want to aggregate values from this pandas table after grouping by `name`:

```
name  id  c   
john  a1  10  
john  a1  10
bob   a2  20
mary  a3  30
```

specifically i want to sum the values of `c`, grouped by `name`, but only for instances where `id` is unique. `df.groupby(["id"]).agg({"c": np.sum})` is not right because the two `a1` entries would have their `c` values summed. i want only unique values of `id` to contribute to the sum of `c` values. how can you write this in pandas?

Comment: What should happen to the duplicate entry then?

Comment: @niyas: discarded. if there are multiple entries with same ``id`` but different ``c`` reasonable behavior is to take only the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
df.drop_duplicates(['name', 'id'], keep='first', inplace=True)
df = df.groupby('name').sum().reset_index()
```